# Convert specific parts of string to uppercase?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` and I'd like to make only specific parts of strings to be made uppercase with an underscore afterwords.

```
|         TYPE       |  NAME  |
|-----------------------------|
| Contract Employee  | John   |
| Full Time Employee | Carol  |
| Temporary Employee | Kyle   |
```

I'd like the words "Contract" and "Temporary" made into uppercase like this with an underscore after and before the word:

```
|         TYPE         |  NAME  |
|-------------------------------|
| _CONTRACT_ Employee  | John   |
| Full Time Employee   | Carol  |
| _TEMPORARY_ Employee | Kyle   |
```

I tried using str.upper() but that made the entire cell uppercase and I'm looking only for those certain words.

EDIT: I should mention sometimes the words are not capitalized if that matters. Often it will display as `temporary employee` instead of `Temporary Employee`.

Comment: Using replace with dict is simplest one in this  use case, which panda provides.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one option using `re.sub`:

```
def type_to_upper(match):
    return match.group(1).upper()

text = "Contract Employee"
output = re.sub(r'\b(Contract|Temporary)\b', type_to_upper, text)
```

**EDIT:**

This is the same approach applied within pandas, also addressing the latest edit regarding uncertain upper or lower case words to be replaced:

test dataframe:

```
                 TYPE   NAME
0   Contract Employee   John
1  Full Time Employee  Carol
2  Temporary Employee   Kyle
3   contract employee   John
4  Full Time employee  Carol
5  temporary employee   Kyle
```

solution:

```
def type_to_upper(match):
    return '_{}_'.format(match.group(1).upper())

df.TYPE = df.TYPE.str.replace(r'\b([Cc]ontract|[Tt]emporary)\b', type_to_upper)
```

result:

```
df 
                   TYPE   NAME
0   _CONTRACT_ Employee   John
1    Full Time Employee  Carol
2  _TEMPORARY_ Employee   Kyle
3   _CONTRACT_ employee   John
4    Full Time employee  Carol
5  _TEMPORARY_ employee   Kyle
```

Note that this is only for addressing exactly these two cases which are defined in the OPs request. For complete case insensitivity it's even simpler:

```
df.TYPE = df.TYPE.str.replace(r'\b(contract|temporary)\b', type_to_upper, case=False)
```

Comment: But implementing into pandas dataframe?

Comment: @U9-Forward I know zero about Pandas data frames.  I will let the OP comment if this answer is really not helpful at all.

Comment: It's okay, still nice :-)

Comment: I do need it in a pandas dataframe. Theoretically I could `apply` it to the column but I'd like a more inline solution rather than creating unnecessary functions.

Comment: @ATCH_torn Fair enough.  I can delete this if a better answer comes along.

Answer (score 2):

Something that modifies the data-frame (without regex or anything):

```
l=['Contract','Temporary']
df['TYPE']=df['TYPE'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(['_'+i.upper()+'_' if i in l else i for i in x.split()]))
```

`join` and `split`, being in a `apply`.

And then now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
                   TYPE   NAME
0   _CONTRACT_ Employee   John
1    Full Time Employee  Carol
2  _TEMPORARY_ Employee   Kyle
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simples and easy way by using `replace` with dictionary format.

Please [refer pandas Doc for Series.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html)

```
df["TYPE"] = df["TYPE"].replace({'Contract': '_CONTRACT_', 'Temporary': '_Temporary_'}, regex=True)
```

Just reproduced:

```
>>> df
                 TYPE   Name
0   Contract Employee   John
1  Full Time Employee  Carol
2  Temporary Employee   Kyle

>>> df["TYPE"] = df["TYPE"].replace({'Contract': '_CONTRACT_', 'Temporary': '_TEMPORARY_'}, regex=True)
>>> df
                   TYPE   Name
0   _CONTRACT_ Employee   John
1    Full Time Employee  Carol
2  _TEMPORARY_ Employee   Kyle
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the OP's EDIT, which tells that you can't rely on uppercase first characters.

Comment: @SpghttCd, this works , simply you need to place the new value in a way you want to look it, edited my answer..

Comment: Sorry, but _this_ in the meaning of _this what you posted above_ does not. If you already took care about the EDIT, then IMO you should address it in your post, otherwise nobody can know.

Comment: @SpghttCd, sorry about that but its just a  value name which can be modified as required as being simplest :- ) will take care for future reference

Comment: Hmm - I think we're misunderstanding each other, as I don't understand what you mean by _'just a value name'_, but I feel that you think your code creates all the replacements required by the OP, which is not the case. Did you realize, that 'Contract' can often be 'contract' and the same with the upper 'T' of 'Temporary'?

Comment: If you will look at the OP's Edit , those column values may be  uppercase or lowercase  , in OP's words `temporary employee instead of Temporary Employee` , so better approach would be  dictionary based replacement as its provided in the answer , so whatever needs to be replaced  that can based on as `{'old_value':'new_value'}` desired.

Answer (score 1):

U9 beat me to it, using `lambda` and `split()` on the input:

```
def match_and_upper(match):
    matches = ["Contract", "Temporary"]
    if match in matches:
        return match.upper()
    return match

input = "Contract Employee"
output = " ".join(map(lambda x: match_and_upper(x), input.split()))
# Result: CONTRACT Employee #
```

Comment: You say i beat you to it :D , Happens to me times too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Answering part of my own question here. Using @Tim Biegeleisen's regex he provided, I did a string replace on the column.

```
df["TYPE"] = df["TYPE"].str.replace(r'\b(Contract)\b', '_CONTRACT_')
```

Comment: @ ATCH_torn, see my answer thats is easy and no need to  create a function or use lambda exp though.